# Raw HTTP - Using full URL in the GET line?

Tags: php, http

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

header('content-type: text/plain');

$host='www.google.com';

$fp = fsockopen($host, 80);

$out = "GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$out .= "Host: $host\r\n";
$out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $out);

while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fgets($fp, 128);
}

?>
```

this just works.

is it standards compliant?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1):

```
Request-Line = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF
```

...and...

```
Request-URI = "*" | absoluteURI | abs_path | authority
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to [5.1.2 of RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.2):

> An example Request-Line would be:
>
> ```
>   GET http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
> ```
>
> To allow for transition to `absoluteURIs` in all requests in future versions of HTTP, all HTTP/1.1 servers **MUST** accept the `absoluteURI` form in requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients will only generate them in requests to proxies.